# Hilt - Should I @Provides my Base URL or API Key?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am new to Hilt and have negligible experience in Dagger 2 as well.

I am now doing a simple sample project for my self-learning, and trying to apply Hilt.

I use Retrofit to call APIs.

So, I am trying to refactor my code into using Hilt:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object WeatherAPIModule {

    private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"

    @Provides
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideGsonConverterFactory(): GsonConverterFactory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .build()

    }

    @Provides
    fun provideWeatherService(retrofit: Retrofit): OpenWeatherService {
        return retrofit.create(OpenWeatherService::class.java)
    }

    val weatherApiKey by lazy {
        ApiKeyStore.getWeatherApiKey()
    }

}
```

My question is, **Should I use @Provides on Base URL and API Key as well?**

### Why do I ask

According to my understanding, if I have a class like this:

```kotlin
class SomeClass @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject lateinit var someString: String

    ...

}
```

Hilt will try to find modules that provides `String`, and inject that String here. But clearly that's not what I want.

**What should be the best way to do this?**

Especially for `weatherApiKey`. I think I should not have leave it as an ordinary function, because that would lose the point of using Hilt at all.

Comment: It's really up to you. If you think URL and KEY are "dependencies" (I think you should), then provide it. If you want to distinguish between multiple provided strings use [Qualifiers](https://medium.com/mindorks/qualifiers-in-dagger-android-development-c0574cca87a2).

Comment: @skywall After some more researches I ended up using Qualifiers as well. Thank you!